# failed to connect to MySQL at localhost: 3306 with user root

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I have installed both mysql server and mysql workbench. I need to connect to mysql using the workbench interface. I used to do this easily in Windows since the server installation is also in graphical user interface.

But now I'm work in Ubuntu 18 machine. When I try to test the connection after I enter the `root` password I get this error:

I did this command to make sure the password is correct:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user set authentication_string = PASSWORD('mypass') where user = 'root' and host = 'localhost';
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit()
```

Then when I try this and enters the password, I get error again:

```
x@x-VirtualBox:~$ mysql -u root -p -h > localhost -P 3306
Enter password: 
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '-P' (2)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong please? how to make a database connection?

**EDIT:** 
The service is surely running. Here is the test:

```
x@x-VirtualBox:~$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-07-28 20:54:14 WIB; 6min ago
  Process: 12790 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/m
  Process: 12779 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
 Main PID: 12792 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 28 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─12792 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pi

Jul 28 20:54:13 e-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jul 28 20:54:14 e-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Using the command line, I enter the root password and it works. But the workbench does not accept it.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysql.user` table has several entries for the root user, and different ones are used based on how you're connecting (e.g. via a local unix-domain socket or via the tcp port). It looks like you've changed the password for one of the entries but not the others.

Your options are:

- change the passwords for all root user entries in `mysql.user` or
- change "connection method" in the workbench (as seen in your screenshot) from "standard" to "local socket" so that it'll use the same password as when you log in via command line